# Why does Leiningen keep its own JVM running?

Tags: clojure, jvm, leiningen

If I call

```
lein trampoline repl
```

Leiningen launches its own JVM process which then starts a separate JVM for the repl and quits.  However calling the default

```
lein repl
```

leaves two JVMs running.  Is there any reason for keeping the original Leiningen JVM process running?  Why not make `lein trampoline` behavior the default and quit every time?

Comment: namespace separation ? http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/lein-trampoline/

Comment: That would break the process tree, preventing the processes from being cleaned up when something happens to the parent process that started lein.

Comment: It's perfectly clear why `lein` starts a separate JVM, there are plenty of reasons to do so. By why keeping original JVM running for the whole time?

Comment: @nha great article, I read it last year. It explains how `trampoline` works and when it should be used. But it doesn't answer the question why not always use `trampoline`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lein help trampoline` states:

> Run a task without nesting the project's JVM inside Leiningen's.
>
> Calculates the Clojure code to run in the project's process for the
>   given task and allows Leiningen's own JVM process to exit before
>   running it rather than launching a subprocess of Leiningen's JVM.
>
> Use this to save memory or to work around stdin issues.
>
> Arguments: ([task-name & args])

So you can see, without `trampoline` the second JVM runs as a sub-process of the first.  That's why the first one can't exit — exiting would disrupt the second.

On the other hand, with `trampoline` the first JVM constructs a shell script which is then executed by the `lein` script to spawn the second JVM.  So in this case, the second JVM is a child of the `lein` script.  [How Clojure Babies are Made: Leiningen's Trampoline](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/lein-trampoline/) covers this in quite a bit of detail.

As to why `trampoline` is not the default, I'm not entirely sure.  But remember that not every `lein` command runs project code, so the second JVM is not needed for every command.

Also, there may be disadvantages to using `trampoline`.  For example, take a look at the following lines of code from the above article:

```
# Just don't change :target-path in project.clj, mkay?
TRAMPOLINE_FILE="target/trampolines/$INPUT_CHECKSUM"
```

To me, that implies that there could be problems if `:target-path` *is* set in `project.clj`.

Comment: Starting the bounty, I hoped to see some more reasoning about why `lein` is not terminating its main process by default. Personally, I believe that `lein` team added `trampoline` to boost its performance, but never trusted it enough to make it `lein`'s default behavior, though I have nothing to prove it. Anyway, your answer is the best one and deserve this bounty.

Answer (score 0):

This is because first instance sets up the environment and passes other required parameters to the real jvm which keeps on running.

First instance of JVM is just a kind of wrapper which is for users ease, otherwise user have to do all those work of passing required parameters at every exeution point, which neither user friendly nor looks good from security point of view.

Comment: Why not make `lein trampoline` behavior the default and quit every time?

Comment: Read the question please.

Comment: Well, the question explicitly asks, "Is there any reason for keeping the original Leiningen JVM process running?".  This seems to answer that, no?